How to iterate a dict within a template that contains a key named items?
I have some fairly simple django template and part of it is iterating through some dict ( that originates from some parsed json files ) like:
{% for k, v in d.items %}

However my dict now contains an item called items, which because for the syntax of a.b django first tries to resolve it as a[b] before trying getattr(a,b) (and calling the result if its callable), will try to iterate through the value under that key instead of the dict.
What would be a good way to resolve that? I know already I could write a filter that simply returns list(d.items()) but that seems wrong/wasteful to me. Are there some other possibilities to solve this problem?

The docs says this Keep in mind that for the dot operator, dictionary key lookup takes precedence over method lookup. Therefore if the data dictionary contains a key named 'items', data.items will return data['items'] instead of data.items(). Avoid adding keys that are named like dictionary methods if you want to use those methods in a template (items, values, keys, etc.)

No, you probably should rewrite the dictionaries to not include 'items' as key, so perhaps 'children' is an alternative.
This is specified in the {% url … %} documentation [Django-doc]:

Keep in mind that for the dot operator, dictionary key lookup takes precedence over method lookup. Therefore if the data dictionary contains a key named 'items', data.items will return data['items'] instead of data.items(). Avoid adding keys that are named like dictionary methods if you want to use those methods in a template (items, values, keys, etc.)

So probably it is better to avoid using items as key. You can "remap" these to a different key with:
{'children' if k == 'items' else k: v for k, v in data.items()}

I have little choice here as the json format is not my own, I just want to provide a way to edit it.

@PlasmaHH: you can remap the items, so if you get the JSON blob, use children for example instead of items.

that sounds really convoluted, at each place I am displaying it I would have to map it back so the user sees items and the same would probably go for when they want to insert a key items etc.

@PlasmaHH: another option might be to let JavaScript do some rendering. Can you explain what the exact use-case is of rendering a JSON blob?

It is a config format that nests basically arbitrarily deep and we want to provide a webinterface as a means to easier configure it. we display it in a more natural format

@PlasmaHH it nests arbitrarily deep? Ah, that might make my answer need to be more complicated. Do you perchance need to loop over sub objects as well?

@PlasmaHH: how do you make type checks to differentiate between lists/dicts/strings/...?

@AbdulAzizBarkat basically atribitraily deep, yes, and it recurses into subobjects

@willeM_VanOnsem with a custom filter that basically does isinstance() in python

One way to solve this problem is to wrap the dictionary up in another object and expose any required methods through it:
class DictionaryWrapper:
    def __init__(self, d):
        self.d = d
    
    def items(self):
        return self.d.items()
    
    # Expose any other appropriate methods as needed


# Example view
def your_view(request):
    # Other code
    d = ...
    d = DictionaryWrapper(d)
    context = {"d": d}
    return render(request, "your_template.html", context)

Then in your template you can do what you were previously doing:
{% for k, v in d.items %}

If you need direct access to the dictionary in the template you can use d.d for that purpose.
Another solution would be to actually create a custom template tag / filter that would get you the suitable iterable.
